# How to fix <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "" }-->

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular6

Im new to Angular. I am creating a button inside game-control component and using event binding and property binding. When i click the button numbers will be entered into an array continuously using setInterval method. I am passing the data between one component to another. The game-control component's selector is called inside the app component. The button worked fine with the click event but when i used the ngFor in order to iterate through the array and display the buttons also did not appear in the dom. Thanks in advance

```
game-control.component.html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  type="button" 
  (click)="gameStart()">Start</button>

<button 
  class="btn btn-danger" 
  type="button" 
  (click)="gameStop()">Stop</button>

  <br>
<p>{{element}}</p>  
  </div>
</div>

game-control.component.ts
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() element:number;
  @Output() createNumber= new EventEmitter<number>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  gameStart()
  {
    this.createNumber.emit(this.element);
  }
}

app.component.html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-game-control                       
      (createNumber)='onStart()'
      *ngFor="let myElement of myHoldings"
      [element]="myElement"
      >  
  </app-game-control>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
 myHoldings=[];

 onStart()
 {
   setInterval(()=>{
    this.myHoldings.push(this.myHoldings.length+1);
    console.log("hello");
   },1000);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have an internal variable in the component that is assigned from the `Input()` variable

```js
@Input() element:number;

internalNumber : number ;

ngOnInit() {
  this.internalNumber = this.number;
}
```

And then use that variable to do bindings or emit events

For a similar question that might help

[Click function not being called for a mat-menu with items generated with ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663139/click-function-not-being-called-for-a-mat-menu-with-items-generated-with-ngfor)